# Ruby on Rails - Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hey I'm just getting started with Ruby on Rails and need some help. I installed Ruby on Rails and then created a project with MySQL but I am unable to connect to the MySQL server to create a database. Side note I am using Windows 10.

After running the command (rake db:create) I get this error.
`#<Mysql2::Error: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost' (10061)>`

Here is my database.yml file

```
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: 5
  username: root
  password: 1234
  host: localhost
```

Comment: What are using to run MySQL server, is it WAMP or something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're running Linux, try the following command to see if MySQL is running:

`/etc/init.d/mysql status`

Make sure you're specifying a `database` name to connect to as well, but that would likely give you a different error code than the one you're seeing.

Comment: No I am using windows 10.

Comment: How did you install Ruby on Rails? Have you installed MySQL Server on your development machine?

Comment: I used the installer from http://rubyinstaller.org/ I thought it already came with the MySQL Server. I also have xampp installed if that means anything.

Comment: You actually want [RailsInstaller](http://railsinstaller.org/en) instead. Ruby is just one part to Ruby on Rails. Check out [InstallRails](http://installrails.com/) for some step-by-step guides that will get you up and running!

Comment: My mistake I meant RailsInstaller. I just realized however I forgot to add the socket and point it to xampp's mysql. The server seems to be working now that I have the socket added.